Blank measures in the end of the score
I am creating a score using Music21. However, when I generate the MusicXML file and open it in MuseScore, I notice that it contains many blank measures at the end of the score, after the notes that were intentionally included. How can I generate the MusicXML file without these unwanted blank measures?
`!pip install music21
from music21 import *

score = stream.Score()

part1 = stream.Part()
part2 = stream.Part()

part1.append(instrument.Violoncello())
part2.append(instrument.Viola())

part1.append(meter.TimeSignature('4/4'))  # Define the time signature
part2.append(meter.TimeSignature('4/4'))  # Define the time signature

# Add 10 measures with notes in the first part
for i in range(100):
    # Add some random notes for each measure
    part1.append(note.Note('C4', quarterLength=1))
    part1.append(note.Rest(quarterLength=1))
    part1.append(note.Note('E4', quarterLength=1))
    part1.append(note.Rest(quarterLength=1))
    part1.append(note.Note('G4', quarterLength=1))
    part1.append(note.Note('C5', quarterLength=1))

# Add 10 measures with notes in the second part
for i in range(100):
    # Add some random notes for each measure
    part2.append(note.Note('C3', quarterLength=1))
    part2.append(note.Note('E3', quarterLength=1))
    part2.append(note.Rest(quarterLength=1))
    part2.append(note.Note('G3', quarterLength=1))
    part2.append(note.Note('C4', quarterLength=1))

# Create the combined score
score.append(part1)
score.append(part2)

# Save the combined score
score.write('musicxml', fp='combined_score.musicxml')`

I tried creating functions to delete blank spaces or to remove rests at the end of the score, but it seems that the problem occurs when inserting the part into the score.

To have a coherent score, both parts need to be the same length.  You have 600 notes in the first part and 500 in the other.  What music software chooses to do with scores like that is entirely at their discretion.
